# Responsive height HTML

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, pug

I am trying to achieve two panel website that is responsive to all scren sizes, similar to http://hdwr.co/

However, I cannot figure out how to make each section fit to screen.

CSS

```
.cover {
width: 100%;
height: 69.5em;
margin: 0 auto;
overflow: hidden;
position: relative;
}
```

Jade/HTML:

```
.bangerscreen
    img.cover.img-responsive( src="/assets/images/background.png" )
.signupscreen
    img.cover.img-responsive( src="/assets/images/sign_up.png" )
```

Comment: are you using Bootstrap?

Comment: Yes I am using Bootstrap.

Comment: The website you mentioned is using following jQuery plugin [fullPage.js](http://alvarotrigo.com/blog/fullpage-jquery-plugin-for-fullscreen-scrolling-websites/)

Comment: Thanks Ramis. So that plugin handles both the responsive screen and scrolling?

Answer (score 0):

set the height of two element to the Outer window height using jquery.

have a look at this bootply:- 
http://www.bootply.com/m7iFTvjKx0